# unable to run Tor browser

Tags: firefox, tor

Downloaded, extracted, and executed, then I got "`tor unexpected exited`".
Here are some terminal stuffs:

```
tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser    
Launching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in /home/jackbutton/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US    
(process:6331): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed    
(process:6331): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed    
Tor Browser exited cleanly.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672671), for which no sure workaround is known. For some users, [it seems to be a permission problem](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973503#answer-503116), while [some users had success](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973503#answer-524270) removing custom themes and using default widget styles.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it was a permission problem, because firstly I copied whole folder with Tor browser to NTFS partition and then back to ext4 partition. Apparently, executable bits on some files were lost. I solved it with not very nicely, but it works for me:

```
chmod -R +x ./
```

inside directory with Tor browser.